# Find the value of $\left(\cos 52^{\circ}+\cos 68^{\circ}+\cos 172^{\circ}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find $\left(\cos 52^{\circ}+\cos 68^{\circ}+\cos 172^{\circ}\right)$
>
> $\color{green}{a.)\ 0 }\\
> b.)\ 1 \\
> c.)\ 2 \\
> d.)\ \text{none of these} $

In exam I often fail to remember the formula's of

$\sin(A)\pm \sin(B) \\
\cos(A)\pm \cos(B) \\
\sin(A)\pm \cos(B) \\
$

so I wonder if there is any other general method to tackle this problem.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Note: I can't use calculator.

Comment: the quetion is how to remember the formulas?

Comment: @Mithlesh not a real duplicate, because the question is if there is a way to solve it *without* the sum formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

$$\cos 52^0 =\cos (60^0-8^0)$$

$$\cos 68^0 =\cos (60^0+8^0)$$

$$\cos 172^0 =\cos (180^0-8^0)=- \cos 8^0$$

Comment: I have reviewed the Duplicate question and the lab battcharjee's answer there which doesn't use described formula's and also this one too.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a unit circle and mark the unit vectors $a$ at $68^\circ+52^\circ=120^\circ,$ $b$ at $52^\circ$ and $c$ at $52^\circ-172^\circ=-120^\circ.$ Call $e$ the unit vector on the positive $X$ axis. Then the sum you are looking for is

$$\eqalign{\cos 52^{\circ}+\cos 68^{\circ}+\cos 172^{\circ}
&=b.e+a.b+b.c\\
&=b.(a+c+e)\\
&=b.o\\
&=0
}$$